# iPython: cannot import module named sklearn

Tags: python, ipython, python-import, jupyter-notebook

I am able to import sklearn using the python interpreter, but when I try to do the same in an iPython notebook, iPython throws an ImportError. Any idea what is causing this issue? I need to use a module in iPython.

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure if this will be helpful, but here is a subset of the packages that I have installed on my machine.

[image]

I followed the instructions here regarding the installation process: 
http://shanshanchen.com/2013/05/29/install-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn-on-mac-os-x-for-data-miners/

Comment: Is ipython using the same python ? The only thing I can think of it is ipython using different version of python or you need to restart it. Are you manually installing all packages? You can check `which python` and `which ipython`.

Comment: I was using a mix of easy_install and pip to grab the various packages (I was installing them over time, via an as-needed basis). Calling `which ipython` generated `/usr/local/bin/ipython` and `which python` generated `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: Oh well, I was able to get things working by just reinstalling everything all at once via: http://fonnesbeck.github.io/ScipySuperpack/ . 
Not sure what was going on before, but at least it works now!

Answer (score 4):

The problem could be solved by the below commands in the notebook.

```
!pip install scipy
!pip install sklearn
```