# sklearn cannot be imported in jupyter

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I have installed anaconda. I can import panda, matplotlib but cannot import sklearn. I have installed sklearn and it also shows that it is installed,but cannot import it in jupyter. here is what it says

[image]

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753731/ipython-cannot-import-module-named-sklearn

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with the `--upgrade` flag.

> -U, --upgrade               Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. The handling of
> dependencies depends on the upgrade-strategy used.

Use this:

```
!pip install -U scikit-learn
```